# issue recognising DataContract in WCF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, datacontract

Having a bit of trouble understanding why visual studio isn't acknowledging the DataContract and DataMembers as they should be. I have the reference and namespace using statement for System.Runtime.Serialization in the project. If anyone has run into this I'd sure appreciate some help.

[image]

Comment: Have you added a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`?

Comment: As Rohit said, you need to add a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`. Also, you don't need to declare a backing field for your properties. `public string PName{get; set;}` will do the trick, and makes your code a little bit more tidy.

Comment: as stated in the question this reference was declared...

Comment: What exactly is error you get when you hover over the `DataContract` attribute? Can't reproduce after adding reference and using statement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strange, still didnt figure out WHY this was happening, but I removed the refrence to System.Runtime.Serialization.dll in the project refrences and re-added it and now everything works

Comment: If that's the case, I bet if you had clicked "Rebuild" for the project the error would go away. Sometimes VS does this.